# How to get bounding boxes for jpg/png in latex

Tags: luatex, pdf, dvi, bounding-box

Currently i include png/jpg files with `graphicx` package
compiling with `lualatex`, no problem, in particular no error message because of bounding box not found.

This question is about historic ways to compile because I don't want to break old code.

First question: Is it true that when compiling into pdf with any of the modern compilers
like `lualatex` with `graphicx` package command `includegraphics`,
there is no special treatment necessary to get a bounding box?

Second, I seem to have no problem with bounding box either when compiling into `dvi`.
What makes me a bit nervous is, that I remember that message.
I am sure i used package `bmpsize` and also command `ebb` to get the bounding box
and this was necessary to avoid the error message

```
cannot determine the size of the graphic
```

But I cannot remember the details.

My question is whether the issue with the bounding box is resolved by new compilers,
even if compiling into `dvi` or `xdv`.
I made a remark by hand, that `bmpsize` does not work with `xelatex`.
Is it obsolete?
May it be the case that behavior depends on the source of the jpg/png?

Are there aspects related with the dvi to pdf converters?
Are there other formats needing `bmpsize` or `ebb`?
Please feel free to mention other aspects also.

I am afraid about dropping ebb or bmpsize when there is still a use case.

In the meantime I found out that my problem is specific for texlive distribution.
Seemingly miktex neither provides `bmpsize` nor `ebb`.

Comment: are you asking how to change the size of pics in LaTeX? or

Comment: no I ask where the error message is gone. 
And i wonder whether it is just the new version of latex which can find the bounding box. 
Before I had to fiddle around with ebb and with bpmsize package.

Answer (score 2):

You should not often see that message in "recent" (say within last 20 years or so) releases.

Firstly pdflatex and lualatex can read the size of the png, jpg and pdf formats they can include, secondly engine/driver combinations that require a separate image size extraction program (like the old `ebb`) have mostly all been written to call `extractbb` (which is actually the same binary as the `xdvipdfmx` dvi driver. `extractbb`  is in the default list of programs allowed by restricted shell escape, so you do not need to call this explicitly, latex can call it in the  background if needed.